# C# Null Conditional Operator alternative (conditional assignment)?

Tags: c#, short-circuiting, null-conditional-operator

The [C# null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) allows for useful short circuiting:

```
double? range = (unit as RangedUnit)?.WeaponRange;
```

Unfortunately the null-conditional operator cannot be used in the same way for short hand assignment, because it returns a value (which cannot be used in left handed assignment):

```
(unit as RangedUnit)?.PreferredTarget = UnitType.Melee;
```

resulting in possible alternative syntax:

```
if (unit is RangedUnit)
{
    (unit as RangedUnit).PreferredTarget = UnitType.Melee;
}
```

If the compiler knows that RangedUnit is a reference type (not a value type), why can it not conditionally execute the shorthand syntax

```
refTypeInstance?.SomeField = value;
```

(i.e. If refTypeInstance is null, then simply do nothing. If refTypeInstance is not null, then execute the statement)

**UPDATE (CONCLUSION):**

- The null-conditional operator cannot be used in the left hand side of an assignment statement because this would violate the expected evaluation logic of an assignment statement's expression tree (short circuiting an assignment operation and not performing it at all)
- The ideal solution is a new conditional-assignment operator (executes only if the left hand side of an assignment is not null), in essence a 'if not null one assignment one liner'

Comment: I think it would be a major flaw (or at least highly confusing) if the assignment you want simply did nothing if `unit` was `null` (or not of type `RangedUnit`).

Comment: I like the idea, but your question boils down to "Why didn't they implement it like this and that?" and we don't know their motivation or decision process.

Comment: That "then simply do nothing" would not be very obvious to the reader. So it's a debatable feature, I wouldn't want it.

Comment: I think `?.` operator becoming bad practice for readability when you start using it every where.

Comment: Not everything needs a shortcut.

Comment: Actually it's supported, but only for method calls and not property/field assignments. So `(unit as RangedUnit)?.SetPreferredTarget(UnitType.Melee);`  would work (if you replace the property setter with method).

Comment: Sometimes i think people try to hide their bugs with the null-conditional operator. That's the same as using a `try{..}catch(Exception){}` everywhere and often you notice that bug somewhere else. Or even the customer notices it, what is the worst case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `foo?.DoSomething()` arguably does nothing too if `foo` is `null` so I'm not sure thats a convincing argument unless you are outright against the null conditional operator to begin with ;).

Comment: If I'm assigining to a property of an object that is null, I want to know as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jodrell unless `null` is an expected value of the object. I'm not convinced by any of the arguments against this feature in the comments above. The whole point of `.?` is to act as a syntactic sugar to avoid explicit and cumbersome `null` checks poluting your code. If you are using it, its because you *expect* something can be `null`, not to hide/swallow a `NullReferenceException`; that would be a misuse of the feature and based upon this argument, `.?` should be removed altogether from the language, not only the OP's proposed feature.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But that doesn't mean we need to get rid of `try{..}catch(Exception){}` does it?. Just because a feature can be misused doesn't mean it doesn't have its own merits. I find the OP's proposal reasonable and coherent with how `.?` works. My guess is that it was not implemented due to more "mundane" reasons along the lines of Sefe's answer.

Comment: Appreciate the insights, they add significant weight to the argument against short hand syntax. The elaborate syntax (third snippet) is arguably the best practice considering overall impact (especially to avoid bug prone code).

Comment: Based on Sefe's answer below does assignment not have the lowest precedence of all 
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Therefore, the lexer should always be evaluating the conditional null operator before assignment and therefore be able to short circuit to no action if a left hand side reference type is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are expecting:

> (i.e. If refTypeInstance is null, then simply do nothing. If refTypeInstance is not null, then execute the statement)

Is not possible because of the way operators work. More specifically, you have a problem with **operator precedence** and how expression trees are formed based on that:

In the statement

```
(unit as RangeUnit).PreferredTarget = UnitType.Melee;
```

The assignment operator (`=`) would be in the root of the expression tree, with the left and the right expressions as branches.

A `NullReferenceException` would occur when the left hand is evaluated (before assignment). At this point the compiler **has already started to evaluate the `=`**. Since the dereference operator (`.`) will throw a `NullReferenceException` at runtime, it is safe for the compiler to just continue parsing the expression tree.

On the other hand if this statement would permitted:

```
(unit as RangeUnit)?.PreferredTarget = UnitType.Melee;
```

...the compiler would have to emit code to check whether the value of `refTypeInstance` is null. It could do that, but the problem is, what would the compiler do with the expression tree that it is currently going through? It can not simply go on like in the first example, because it would have to discard the `=` up the expression tree and the `.` down the tree. It would basically have to insert two alternatives of parsing the tree, one when the left of `?.` is `null` and one when it isn't. That however would be an alteration of the control flow, which is definitely **not** what you expect from an operator.

Or to put it differently: when long as `?.` just short-circuits the evaluation of operators down its branch of the expression tree, you would consider this an expected behavior. But in this case this would alter the behavior of a operator *higher up in the expression tree*, which you would definitely not expect.

Comment: `That however would be an alteration of the control flow, which is defenitely not what you expect from an operator.`. Is that so? `foo?.DoSomething()` alters the control flow as far as I am aware; there are clearly to execution branches: if `foo` is `null` do nothing, otherwise call `DoSomething()`.

Comment: @InBetween: Yes, but it can just jump out of the expression, which is basically the same as short-cirquit evaluation with `&&` and `||`. It can not do that in the OPs example, because it would leave the `=` dangling up the operator stack..

Comment: @InBetween: Or shortly: you wouldn't expect to alter the behavior of _higher precedence_ operators.

Comment: @I'm not arguing that. I'm arguing that `.?` effectively alters the control flow because it is essentially and `if-else` in disguise. The way you phrase that last paragraph is misleading.

Comment: @InBetween: I updated my post.

Comment: True, what I'm asking for probably interferes with the default lexical evaluation order and should therefore be dismissed. C# has evolved so well already to strike a good balance between robustness and efficiency.

Comment: @Sefe, in your answer you listed assignment with a higher precedence that the other operators. Does assignment not have the lowest precedence of all (and is therefore evaluated last)? [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx] In that case, the lexer should always be evaluating the conditional null operator before assignment and therefore be able to short circuit to no action if a left hand side reference type is null?

Comment: @Fortmann: You are right, I updated my post to correct that. It is ultimately about how the expression tree is evaluated.

Comment: Agreed, the operator logic cannot override expression evaluation logic - as this would violate fundamental logical thinking when reading code. To conclude, I would desire a nice to have 'conditional assignment' operator. I.e. assign only if the left side is not null. It would then be clear to the coder what the operator is doing, and how it would (conditionally) execute.

Comment: Yes, let's wait for the `?=` operator ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because they're not doing the same thing,

The first snippet will return null if unit is null (or is not a ranged unit).

If that were to happen as you were trying to set something then you wouldn't be able to set null to value (and you'd end up with an error).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Oh yes thanks

Comment: Yes, that was intentional. The first snippet was intended to introduce and describe the null conditional operator as an entry point, however the request described by the rest of the question may involve another solution (hence inclusion of the word 'alternative' in the question header).